# Apache Cordova Android Push Notification Aerogear Unable To Send

Tags: android, json, curl, cordova, curl-commandline

While using

`curl -3 -u \
"f07c43a6-bb0a-4bb7-a1eb-a368db272212:e2cf19c3-6636-4712-bbe8-26b7c1ac9c09" \
   -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" \
   -X POST -d '{"message": {"alert":"Hello AeroGear", "badge":1}}' \
   https://aerogear-html5.rhcloud.com/rest/sender`

to push notification
I am getting 401 unauthorised request.Unable to figure out how to authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your authorization parameters(through `-u`) are valid and also make sure you are using the correct credential for the service you are trying to access.

Also, if you are from `windows`(for `linux` its ok) then wrap the post parameters with double quotes(`"`) Instead of single(`'`).

```
-d "{\"message\": {\"alert\":\"Hello AeroGear\", \"badge\":1}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Going to this link https://aerogear-html5.rhcloud.com, produces a website not available

Is there a specific tutorial you used to get that curl command?